# Does an antimagic field affect the solarian's mote?

Tags: starfinder, antimagic-field

The [Solarian's](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/solarian/) [Solar Manifestation](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/solarian/#Solar_Manifestation_Su_1st_Level) ability says in the description:

> Only you can interact with your solar manifestation, whether in mote, armor, or weapon form. No other creature or effect can affect your Solar Manifestation in any way, including disarming or sundering it.

Since it's a supernatural ability, it is magical, but since it says that no effect can affect it, is it not effected by an antimagic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

As you quote, *only* you yourself can affect your mote.  Nothing and no one else can do so.  In Starfinder, antimagic fields are a sort of general environmental effect and precisely the sort of thing that the quoted line of text is meant to protect against.